# Speed Up Python Programs (Adaptive Median Filter)

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, image-processing, filtering

Hi can someone improve this code ? The code is about Adaptive Median Filter. When working on large image the code is so slow.

```
import numpy as np

def padding(img,pad):

    padded_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0]+2*pad,img.shape[1]+2*pad))
    padded_img[pad:-pad,pad:-pad] = img
    return padded_img

def AdaptiveMedianFilter(img,s=3,sMax=7):

    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        raise Exception ("Single channel image only")

    H,W = img.shape
    a = sMax//2
    padded_img = padding(img,a)

    f_img = np.zeros(padded_img.shape)

    for i in range(a,H+a+1):
        for j in range(a,W+a+1):
            value = Lvl_A(padded_img,i,j,s,sMax)
            f_img[i,j] = value

    return f_img[a:-a,a:-a] 

 def Lvl_A(mat,x,y,s,sMax):

    window = mat[x-(s//2):x+(s//2)+1,y-(s//2):y+(s//2)+1]
    Zmin = np.min(window)
    Zmed = np.median(window)
    Zmax = np.max(window)

    A1 = Zmed - Zmin
    A2 = Zmed - Zmax

    if A1 > 0 and A2 < 0:
        return Lvl_B(window)
    else:
        s += 2 
        if s <= sMax:
            return Lvl_A(mat,x,y,s,sMax)
        else:
             return Zmed

def Lvl_B(window):

     h,w = window.shape
    Zmin = np.min(window)
    Zmed = np.median(window)
    Zmax = np.max(window)

    Zxy = window[h//2,w//2]
    B1 = Zxy - Zmin
    B2 = Zxy - Zmax

    if B1 > 0 and B2 < 0 :
        return Zxy
    else:
        return Zmed
```

Is there any way to improve this code ? For example using vectorized sliding window ? I dont know how to use what numpy function. Ps: For boundary checking its using padding so it dont have to check for out of bounds.

Comment: in `Lvl_B` you re-compute min, median and max for the window. Instead, pass it from `Lvl_A` as an argument. Don't know how often this function is called, but not repeating computations should be the first thing to look into.

Comment: Apologies that this is not directly related to the question. Shouldn't  the last line of the function Lvl_A return Zxy (rather than Zmed)? If we reach that point, then haven't we determined that Zmed is an unsuitable value to assign (it equals the min or the max at all scales)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **numba's `njit`** is perfect for such kind of computation. Mixed with the `parallel=True`+`prange` it can be **much faster**. Moreover, you can pass the minimum, maximum and median values to `Lvl_B` rather than *recomputing* them as @CrisLuengo pointed out.

Here is the modified code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit,prange


@njit
def padding(img,pad):
    padded_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0]+2*pad,img.shape[1]+2*pad))
    padded_img[pad:-pad,pad:-pad] = img
    return padded_img

@njit(parallel=True)
def AdaptiveMedianFilter(img,s=3,sMax=7):
    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        raise Exception ("Single channel image only")

    H,W = img.shape
    a = sMax//2
    padded_img = padding(img,a)

    f_img = np.zeros(padded_img.shape)

    for i in prange(a,H+a+1):
        for j in range(a,W+a+1):
            value = Lvl_A(padded_img,i,j,s,sMax)
            f_img[i,j] = value

    return f_img[a:-a,a:-a] 

@njit
def Lvl_A(mat,x,y,s,sMax):
    window = mat[x-(s//2):x+(s//2)+1,y-(s//2):y+(s//2)+1]
    Zmin = np.min(window)
    Zmed = np.median(window)
    Zmax = np.max(window)

    A1 = Zmed - Zmin
    A2 = Zmed - Zmax

    if A1 > 0 and A2 < 0:
        return Lvl_B(window, Zmin, Zmed, Zmax)
    else:
        s += 2 
        if s <= sMax:
            return Lvl_A(mat,x,y,s,sMax)
        else:
             return Zmed

@njit
def Lvl_B(window, Zmin, Zmed, Zmax):
    h,w = window.shape

    Zxy = window[h//2,w//2]
    B1 = Zxy - Zmin
    B2 = Zxy - Zmax

    if B1 > 0 and B2 < 0 :
        return Zxy
    else:
        return Zmed
```

This code is *500 times faster* on my machine with a 256x256 random image.

Note that the first call will not be much faster due to the (included) compilation time.

Note also that the computation can be even faster by not recomputing the min/max/median for each value as the sliding windows share many values (see the paper [constant time median filtering (Perreault et al, 2007)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4287006?arnumber=4287006)).

Comment: Hi thankyou for your suggestion. I fixed the code -- not recomputing the min,median,and max also using numba and yes its blazing fast. I also looked up the paper you mentioned but my brain failed to understand haha. If you were so kind to enlighten me it would be great for my learning journey but nevertheless thank you. The speed improved from 60s / image to 3s/image (20x faster)

Comment: 3 second is a bit high. What is the size of the images? How many images do you compute? What are the input parameter (`s` and `sMax`)? As for the paper, it is a bit complex to explain. However, if `s` is very small, writing a faster implementation should not be so hard. You can for example precompute part of the median of the image using (partial) incremental sorts per block line: you can sort the first window value, compute the median from the sorted values, remove the `s` old values, add `s` new values to the end of the sorted array and resort them using a custom insertion sort.

Comment: Hi jerome my image is about 800x800 with s =3 and sMax=7. I have about 1k images to be computed and it quite fast after the first one. I think the total time is about 30mins (ps i do another process to those images too) As your suggestion it might be good idea and (might)  be faster than numpy.median()

Comment: Ok. The difference seems to come from the recursive calls that do not happen on my random data. Note that it is probably a good idea to generate the multiple results with the different kernel/window size first and then select the good one since `sMax` is small. Moreover, using an optimized imaging library may also be a good idea. The OpenCV module for Python could be a good start as I expect they median filter to be quite well optimized.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need in a vectorial way:

```
def adaptive_medfilt(x, ws=3, ws_max=7, axis=(0,1), mode='constant'):
    if isinstance(axis, int): axis = (axis,)
    if isinstance(ws, int): ws = len(axis) * (ws,)
    
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    x_pad = np.pad(x, [2*[ws[axis.index(ax)]//2 if ax in axis else 0] for ax in range(x.ndim)], mode)
    x_stride = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x_pad, ws, axis)
    x_min = np.min(x_stride, tuple(x_stride.ndim-1-np.arange(len(axis))))
    x_med = np.median(x_stride, tuple(x_stride.ndim-1-np.arange(len(axis))))
    x_max = np.max(x_stride, tuple(x_stride.ndim-1-np.arange(len(axis))))
    
    mask1 = (x_med - x_min > 0) * (x_med - x_max < 0)
    mask2 = (x - x_min > 0) * (x - x_max < 0)
    y[mask1 * mask2] = x[mask1 * mask2]
    y[mask1 * ~mask2] = x_med[mask1 * ~mask2]
    y[~mask1] = adaptive_medfilt(x, [ws[ax]+2 for ax in range(len(axis))], ws_max, axis, mode)[~mask1] if all([ws[ax]<=ws_max for ax in range(len(axis))]) else x_med[~mask1]

    return y
```

I tested with a 3-channel random image:

```
x = np.random.randint(256, size=(3, 800, 800))
y = adaptive_medfilt(x, 3, 7, (1, 2), 'constant')
```

and runs in ~8 seconds on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to improve the previous code you can use the code below but note that the input image in this code is grayscale.

```
import numpy as np

def adaptive_median_filter(img_gray, s=3, sMax=7):


    H, W = img_gray.shape
    a = sMax//2



    padded_img = np.pad(img_gray, a)
    f_img = np.zeros(padded_img.shape)

    for i in range(a, H + a + 1):
        for j in range(a, W + a + 1):
        
            f_img[i, j] = Lvl_A(padded_img, i, j, s, sMax)

    return np.array(f_img[a: -a, a: -a], dtype=np.uint8) 


def Lvl_A(mat, x, y, s, sMax):

    window = mat[x - (s//2): x + (s//2) + 1, y - (s//2): y + (s//2) + 1]
    Zmin = np.min(window)

    win_vect = window.reshape(-1)
    Zmed = np.sort(win_vect)[len(win_vect)//2] # O(nlog(n))

    Zmax = np.max(window)

    if Zmin < Zmed < Zmax:
        return Lvl_B(window, Zmin, Zmax, Zmed)
    else:
        s += 2 
        if s <= sMax:
            return Lvl_A(mat, x, y, s, sMax)
        else:
            return Zmed


def Lvl_B(window, Zmin, Zmax, Zmed):

    h, w = window.shape
    Zxy = window[h//2, w//2]

    if Zmin < Zxy < Zmax:
        return Zxy
    else:
        return Zmed
```